# Casting a string from string type to list type

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
x = "list1"
```

How do I use x to find the value in list1?

Since `type(x) = <class str>`  and `list(x) = ["l","i","s","t","1"]`

Answer (score 1):

Usually considered a bad style, but you can use globals()

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
x = "list1"
globals()[x]
```

What you could do instead is create a mapping-dictionary and use .get() to access the list like that:

```
mapping = {"list1": [1, 2, 3]}
mapping.get(x)
```